# constructing js function name dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function this way

```
redBall(this);
```

but I want to dynamically construct from a string. I tried something like this but it's not working.

```
var color = 'red';
color+'Ball'(this);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var ballFunctions = {
    redBall: function(obj) {
        alert("Hi, I'm a red ball");
    },
    blueBall: function(obj) {
        alert("Hi, I'm a blue ball");
    }
};

color = "red";
ballFunctions[color + "Ball"](this);
color = "blue";
ballFunctions[color + "Ball"](this);
```

---

You could also combine this with Jimmy's answer and do:

```
function ball(color, obj) {
    ballFunctions[color + "Ball"](obj);

    // Or use the window object if your funcs are in the global namespace like Cameron said
    // window[color + "Ball"](obj);
}

color = "red";
ball(color, this);
```

Comment: and you can do `ballFunctions['myNewFunction'] = function() { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

Subscript the implicit `window` object:

```
window[color + 'Ball'](this)
```

Your example was attempting to call the string `'Ball'` (which doesn't make sense since strings aren't callable), then concatenate the result with `color` -- not quite what you wanted.

Comment: @jarn: Well, that error means that 'redBall' is not a function in the global namespace (i.e. on the `window` object). Where is it defined? Inside another function? Most importantly, what is `this` in your context?

Answer (score 4):

Dynamically named functions aren't a great practice. What about this?

```
function Ball(color, object)
{ 
     // do stuff
}
```

And then call it via: `Ball('red', this);`

Comment: Functions that do everything aren't that great of a practice either.

Comment: I would still say dynamic function names are a bad way to implement the logic there. A switch statement with other function calls or perhaps a method like Rfvgyhn (that's hard to type) suggested is going to produce much more maintainable code.

Comment: I really have to agree --- there's no way you have to do something this ugly.

Comment: @jarn: JavaScript is not PHP, trying to write PHP in JavaScript will only lead to an ugly mess. Doing this sort of thing is a bad idea so there's no good reason that it should be easy anywhere.

Comment: @mu And honestly, doing that in PHP makes me nervous too. Just because it's easy doesn't make it a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid any modification to your existing code (which I assume is globally scoped) you can use this:

```
window[color + 'Ball'](this);
```

Comment: You're gonna have to show more code, then, and some which reflects actual context.